# Limit of a continuously differentiable function that statisfies

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $x(t)$ be a continuously differentiable for all $t>0$, and such that:

$$\lim_{t\to \infty}[x'(t)+x(t)]=\alpha$$

I need to show that $\lim_{t\to \infty}x(t)=\alpha$

My goal is to show that $\lim_{t\to \infty}x'(t)=0$. I considered the sequence $\{t_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ that converges to $t$ when $n\to \infty$. Then I tried to use $\lim_{n\to \infty}x'(t_n)=x'(\lim_{n\to \infty} t_n)$ by continuity of $x'$. That's all what I could come up with, but I don't think I am heading towards the right direction. Any help/hints is much appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

If you solve the equation near $t\to\infty$,

$$x'(t)+x(t)=\alpha$$

You will obtain:

$$x(t)=\alpha+ce^{-t}$$
$$x'(t)=-ce^{-t}$$

So 
$$\lim_{t\to \infty}x'(t)=0$$
$$\lim_{t\to \infty}x(t)=\alpha$$

Comment: Are we allowed to solve the equation near $\infty$ by just ignoring the limit sign? How can we justify that?